# Iterating in thymleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I was trying to iterate through `functionList` in thymleaf.This is what I done.

Controller :

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/list",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getFunctionList(HttpServletRequest request){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("adminConfigurationFunction");
    List<Function> functionList = functionService.getList();
    mav.addObject("list", functionList);
    return mav;
}
```

and in html :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed margin-top-20">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
<tr th:each="func : ${functionList}" >
<td th:text="${func.name}"></td>
<td th:text="${func.description}"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am new here. What am I doing wrong?Or should I use `th:for`?

Comment: And what is the outcome? th:each is fine

Comment: @MartinFrey the list contained 3 entries but it displayed nothing on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
<tr th:each="func : ${list}" >
<td th:text="${func.name}"></td>
<td th:text="${func.description}"></td>
</tr>
```

changed `th:each="func : ${functionList}"` th:each="func : ${list}"`